# 500 internal server error appearing in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I created a J meter script using Jmeter Recording controller for a web application. I correlated the dynamic values and verified that they are passing correctly in next subsequent calls. on execution of script, one of the call is continuously failing producing 500 internal server error. Total calls =7 in which starting six are passed and 7 is failing with 500 internal server error.

When I execute the application manually following sames steps, this exception does not appear.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the error code, it may be issue with the application code. Make sure you turn debugging mode on to trace the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely not checking for expected results, simply accepting an HTTP 200 as gold for a successful step completion.   Instead, check the actual content of the page and branch your execution when your expected result does not appear.

This 500 class message is very common for the above situation.  The business process comes off the rails one or two pages before the error, but it is not caught.  The next request is then out of synch with the state of the application/business process and a 500 is thrown.